# Can I define which characters are allowed to 'break' a word?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari-extension, wordbreaker

I'm showing up veeeery long URLs in my Safari extension. Obviously, they can't fit on a single line. Currently, word breaking rules make it so most URLs are on two lines: the first one is rather short and ends with the `?` symbol, and the other is ridiculously long and contains all the rest of the `GET` parameters.

I'd like to make it so words also break on the `&` symbol, without screwing up copy-paste if possible. I've tried to replace every `&` with `&\u00ad` (`&` + the soft hyphen character), but it's kind of weird to see the hyphen after the `&` when there really isn't any in the URL.

I thought there was something in store with CSS3 for that kind of problem, but I can't find it.

Any suggestion welcome, as long as it works with Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably [`<wbr>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`<wbr>` is a good answer, but you might also consider the zero-width space entity. I haven't used it much, but [this article](http://gojomo.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-browser-invisible-word-break-in.html) suggests using the following css to extend the cross-browser functionality:

```
wbr:after { content: "\00200B" }
```